# Paypal express checkout session expired / token invalid - Error 10411

Tags: php, api, paypal

i have a big Problem.

I build my own Shop and now i'm trying to integrate Paypal.
I successfully integrated Paypal with Sandbox. Now that I'm changing to the Live Mode an Error appears:

API Error 10411 - This Express Checkout session has expired. Token value is no longer valid.

It doesn't make any sense.. 
Normaly this Error appears if the client needs to much time to complete the transaction, but i don't need more than 30 seconds. 
Actually everything works until reaching the return-Site, here comes the answer "FAILURE" and this error message.

The strange thing is, that everything works fine with Sandbox, but in the Live-mode my token is invalid. I checked the API Name, Password and Signature almost a hundred times and it should work.

Does anybody has any ideas why this Error appears?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you calling the API from a different domain in live mode?

Comment: Can you include a copy of all your API requests as well as your API responses?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

My mistake was :
- SetExpressCheckout was made toward paypal sandbox
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails was made toward real Prod Paypal

So double check that the Token you get from PaypalSandBox is used with PaypalSandbox (and same thing for real Paypal)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, and i was in sandbox mode when checking the token. so always be sure to test against the LIVE system and not the sandbox